# Green Function in Euclidean space time

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conventions, greens-functions, wick-rotation

My question based on Ashok Das's "Finite Temperature Field Theory", page 12-13.

The book assume that in bosonic Klein-Gordon theory, zero temperature Green function satisfies (metric in Minkowski space: $(+,-,-,-)$)
$$ \left(\partial_\mu \partial^\mu+m^2\right) G(x)=-\delta^4(x) \tag{1.31}$$

$\textbf{I am troubled for following statement:}$

When rotating to Euclidean space or imaginary time, we let $t \rightarrow -i\tau$, or $p^0 \rightarrow ip_4$, which leads to $G \rightarrow-\mathcal{G}$, $(1.31)$ become
$$\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \tau^2}+\nabla^2-m^2\right) \mathcal{G}(\vec{x}, \tau)=-\delta^3(x) \delta(\tau) \tag{1.32} $$
why there is a minus sign from $G \rightarrow-\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: I'd say it is a convention designed to make the Euclidean signature Green function positive. emember that it is $-\nabla^2$ that has positive eigenvalues.

Comment: @mikestone Thanks for your comment, could you please explain more about why $G\rightarrow -\mathcal{G}$ after this wick rotation? Or it's just a convention in your comment! So the book's word "which leads to" is the convention meaning? Thanks!